# Why can't I import LDAPBindError from LDAP3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap3

Hi I am trying to import 'LDAPBindError' from the ldap3 library and I am getting an import error. Can somebody please explain why this is not working?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, LDAPBindError, SUBTREE, ALL_ATTRIBUTES,MODIFY_REPLACE

ImportError: cannot import name 'LDAPBindError'
```

I am using the following versions

pip3.6 list |grep ldap3
ldap3 (2.5)

python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.4

Comment: `from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError`

Comment: @Sraw I'm adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All credit goes to *Sraw*, just adding the answer here because I originally missed it in the comments:

```
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError
```

The modules in `ldap3` are organized into [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). I have not found [specific documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html?highlight=LDAPBindError#bind-as-a-different-user-while-the-connection-is-open) for this.